# How to set a S3KeySensor state to skipped in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have let's say five s3keysensors that are scanning five different s3 keys and get itself rescheduled from time to time if nothing found
If one out of the five found the arrival file, I want to stop the rest four sensors
is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I found the answer:

```
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.models import TaskInstance

def set_sensor_state(sensor_list, **kwargs):
    for sensor in sensor_list:
        ti = TaskInstance(sensor, kwargs['execution_date'])
        ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED)
    return 'All sensor set to skipped'
```

then have a PythonOperator to execute this function,
just make sure to have provide_context=True to get the 'execution_date'